# Nexus Proxy Repo does not want to fetch

Tags: maven-2, maven, nexus

I am using nexus 1.9.2. I setup a proxy repo to a remote location (which can be accessed via http://somelocation.com). I added this proxy repo to Nexus' Public Repositories group. My maven's settings.xml is set to use Nexus (in the `<mirror />` section).

When I login to Nexus via a web browser and click on this newly added proxy repo and then to Browse Remote tab I can see all the artifacts. However, when I click the tabs Browse Storage or Browse Index I do not see any artifact.

When I do mvn clean install I do get missing artifact, it simply does not want to fetch from the remote site.

I am getting the following

> 1 required artifact is missing.
>
> for artifact:
>     com.somelocation:someserverapp:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> from the specified remote repositories:
>     release-repo (http://localrepo:8081/nexus/content/groups/public),
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:711)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
> ```
>
> ### Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
>
> 1) com.somelocation:somelocation-networking-packet:jar:1.0.0
>
> Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
>
> Then, install it using the command:
>         mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.somelocation -DartifactId=somelocation-networking-packet -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
>
> Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
>         mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.somelocation -DartifactId=somelocation-networking-packet -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
>
> Path to dependency:
>           1) com.somelocation:someserverapp:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
>           2) com.somelocation:somelocation-networking-packet:jar:1.0.0

Any ideas why?

Comment: what error message are you getting ?  There are many reasons that would make this possible.  try `mvn -e clean install` and see if it can give you more info on what is wrong.

Comment: I think I had some kind of corruptions or "internal" config error because I upgraded my Nexus 1.3.x to 1.9.2 the other day. I just purged my sonatype-work directory and added those proxy repos again and now things worked as expected.

Hope I can share this to others that might have the same problem with me.